# Windows 10 not updating at all

Tags: windows-10, updates

I have had a problem for a while, and don't know what to do anymore.

Everytime I try to update my windows, it gets to about 50%, reboots,
gets to 100%,
then displays a message saying:

```
We couldn’t complete the updates,
Undoing changes.
Don’t turn off your computer.
```

then reboots,
then boots back into Windows fine.

I thought it may be something to do with my dual boot setup, with Windows 10 and Kali Linux, but after deleting Kali, it still happened.

I have tried deleting the contents of the `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\` folder, which didn't work, as well as using the Windows Update Troubleshoot three times.

If anyone has any suggestions, that would be great :)

Here is my system information

[image]

From the image you can see:

```
Edition: Windows 10 Home
Version: 1703
OS build: 15063.608
```

Here is a screenshot of my update history

[image]

As you can see, Everything fails to install.

Whenever I re-install Windows (I do this a lot, the amount of random files annoys me too much), the updates work fine, so it must be something to do with an application I've installed.

So here is the full list:

[image]
[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Comment: What Windows 10 build are you running.  Update your question.  What update was last installed.  Be specific, question is not answerable, without this information

Comment: Start by looking at your update history and finding out which update(s) is failing. Return here and [edit] your question to provide more info.

Comment: Added a lot more information now :)

Comment: You have pending updates that have yet to be installed. **You should restart your system.**  The failed feature update is likely failing because of those pending updates.  `KB4038788 ` was released over 2 months ago, you should finish installing `KB4048954`, so you are running the current version of 1703.  Update your question to reflect this new information, this is a requirement, and I cannot help you determine a solution to your inability to install 1709 unless you finish installing the pending updates.

Comment: How would I install pending updates?

Answer (score 0):

This might or might not help you; it solved the described issue on four machines for me:
I found that this is typically because of some USB device or high monitor resolution. To resolve it, remove all non-essential USB devices, and set your screen resolution to some cheapo-standard (1024x768 or so), run the update, and once completed, put it all back (there should be no problems then, it is only an issue during the upgrading).

I typically need a second reboot after the new version comes up the first time before I can go back to my screen resolution (2560x1680).